# How to filter node by parameters and then apply position() != 1 for result?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Sorry, but I'm real noob in XPath. So, here is my question. Let's suppose that we have structure like this one...

```
<structure>
   <item filter=0>1 do not display</item>
   <item filter=1>2 display</item>
   <item filter=1>3 display</item>
   <item filter=0>4 do not display</item>
</structure>
```

How to apply filter `structure[filter=1]` and select only first element from resulting data?
I suppose it will be something like `structure[filter=1][position() = 1]` ?

PS: Please recommend online xlst testing tool.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost did it yourself.

```
/*/item[@filter = 1][1]
```

Take a look at this example (explicit `value-of` for clarity only):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="*/item[@filter = 1][1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result against this well-formed input:

```
<structure>
   <item filter="0">1 do not display</item>
   <item filter="1">2 display</item>
   <item filter="1">3 display</item>
   <item filter="0">4 do not display</item>
</structure>
```

Will be `2 display`.

To select all items, that match `@filter=1` condition, except the first one of them use this xpath expression:

```
/*/item[@filter = 1][position() > 1]
```